# iOS location issue - can't see any data coming in

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I'm new to iOS programming and trying to get my current location. My main app delegate is like this,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@class AWSViewController;

@interface AWSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AWSViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cities;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;

@end
```

And in the implementation, i have these 2 methods and i call getCurrentLocation from `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

I can see the words "Started to get locations" on the console and I don't see anything else after.

```
-(void)getCurrentLocation {

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Started to get locations");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Got Location");
    NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
thanks

Comment: Your distance filter is set to 500m. Thus, it will only call didUpdateLocations if you move >500m. EDIT: Also, you'd better implement the "-(void) didUpdateLocation:(CLLocation*) loc" delegate.

Comment: I've set it to 5m, but still nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it :D

my locationManager object - I instantiate it but you don't retain so it vanishes instantly in a puff of smoke

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

Then,

```
-(void)getCurrentLocation {

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Started to get locations");
}
```

Now it works perfectly :D

Answer (score 3):

Your location manager goes out of scope as soon as the code exits your `getCurrentLocation` method. Make a location manager ivar so that it stays around.

```
@interface AWSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}



-(void)getCurrentLocation {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your location manager enabled? Check it:

```
if(locationManager.locationServicesEnabled == NO){
  //go to settings>location services
}
```

If something is going bad, the method

```
locationManager:didFailWithError:
```

is called instead of

```
locationManager:didUpdateLocations
```

so, please, implement it:

```
- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"error%@",error);
}
```

Comment: I've implemented it, but still nothing comes through to the console

Comment: wait.. you told @ Kai that you set the distanceFilter at 5 meters and you are talking about NSLog, so your device is connected at your Mac. Are you sure that you are moving 5 meters (horizontally) your phone?

Comment: I was using the simulator and set it to the freeway mode, I manage to solve it :) please see below